# Extend jQuery AJAX Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sapui5

I'm using the HTML5 Neptune framework, to create SAPUI5 applications. At runtime my code gets inserted into the index.html file, mixed in between the code generated from the framework.

In a part of the code below the code area I control, the framework creates an ajax function I would like to modify. I would like to inject code into the jQuery AJAX success callback function. I this possible?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="MobileContent"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="applid" value="XXX">
  </form>
  <script>
    var JSONH, jsonh = JSONH = function(n, r) {
      //Framework code
    }(Array, JSON);

    // framework code
    ...
    // my code
    ...
    // framework code
    ...
    function getOnlineXxx(value) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "neptune_ajax?ajax_id=xxx=" + value + "",
        dataType: "json",
        data: encodeURIComponent(modelXxx.getJSON(),
        success: function(data) {
          // framework code
          // code I would like to execute!!!
        }
      });
    }    
    ....    
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean code to run on the server side?  What you really want to accomplish when the success call back is being called?

Comment: No, code to run on the client side. I want to call another ajax function when the first one returns back in the success callback function. I do not have access to change the backend functionality that is called from the framework AJAX call.

Comment: Promise object could be handy for you!

Comment: Is `getOnlineXxx()` the framework's function that is added when the framework generates the page?

Comment: Correct, the framework adds the getOnlineXxx() function when the page is generated.

Comment: I've ended up with a work around. I have added the code to the the standard Neptune framework code.
This gets the job done, but will have to be checked at every Neptune upgrade...